# Make a hieradata file mandatory?

Tags: puppet

I've been running into problems with on-site configuration occasionally managing to 'lose' one or another of the hieradata configuration files.

Is there any way in hiera.yaml to declare that all instances must have a file that matches one or more of the hiera.yaml entries?

For example, something like the following:

```
hierarchy:
  - name: "Per-Node Data"
    path: nodes/${trusted.certname}.yaml
    required: true
```

And if you ended up in a situation where there was no 'nodes' file of the correct name, puppet would immediately give up and complain.

Comment: You are probably looking at using the `file` function or a custom function for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a great solution but one idea I just came up with:

Have a key called $node_filename that is read into the Puppet class, e.g.

```
class profile::base (
  String $node_filename,
  ...
) {
  if ($node_filename == 'not found') {
    fail("Did not find a node Hiera file for this node ${trusted['certname']}")
  }
  ...
}
```

Then in common.yaml place the default:

```
---
profile::base::node_filename: not found
```

Then in each file in nodes:

```
---
profile::base::node_filename: web01.example.com
```

That leads to a bit of duplication and a maintenance burden of course, and you could use Rspec to ensure that each nodes YAML file has a key that matches its file name, e.g.

```
describe 'YAML nodes files' do
  Dir.glob('hieradata/nodes/*.yaml').each do |f|
    data = YAML::load_file(f)
    it "#{f} should contain a node YAML key that matches the filename" do
      expect(data.has_key?('profile::base::node_filename')).to be true
      expect(data['profile::base::node_filename']).
        to eq File.basename(f).sub('.yaml','')
    end
  end
end
```

As far as I know, there is no built-in mechanism to report back to the Puppet manifests the actual Hiera file name that data was found in, so you might have to come up with something a bit complicated like the above.

Comment: The ```describe``` method looks possible, because there are multiple files that need checking, but I haven't had time to try it out.  Another idea I had, and again haven't had time to try it, is to provide a script that does ```puppet lookup``` and checks for the existence of required parameters; but that would be "outside" the puppet framework, and dependent upon the admin to run it.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at this again, if one was to use Rspec to validate some of this, why not just use Rspec to solve the problem entirely? That's silly of me.